# routing on tap event using panels in senchatouch

Tags: sencha-touch

can anyone let me know how can I redirect to another page in senchatouch on a tap event of a panel.can it be through routes.any example will be of a great help.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Routes are merely design to have access through a custom URL to any view within your app.
First, you need to specify what you mean by "page": is it a specific view of your app or just another panel (probably handled by a container with a card layout).

You would probably better:

- implement a controller that will handle the processing required to switch to the view/panel you want to display
- link the tap event to the function you defined above in the controller (by firing a custom event when tap is triggered or by letting the controller responding directly to the tap).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to fire and event on tap of a panel which should take care of creating new view and pushing it wherever required.

Here is what you can do

```
    Ext.getCmp('myPanelId').element.on({
        tap: function() { 
            console.log('panel tapped!'); 
            me.fireEvent("showAnotherPageCommand");
        }
    });
```

In your controller you should listen this event and do whatever is required like...

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.NewPanel'));
```

I hope it helps.

BTW I totally agree with Josh, [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) That should always be a part of your question.